# What is the covariance between function and its argument?

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, inference, covariance, likelihood

For example, we have log-likelihood function $\ell(\theta)$ and maximum likelihood estimator $\hat \theta_{ML}$ obtained as $\ell(\theta)' = 0$. What would be
$$Cov(\ell(\theta), \hat \theta_{ML}) ?$$

For simplicity let's assume that MLE is unbiased.

Comment: should it be $\hat\theta_{ML}$ in the argument of $\ell$?

Comment: Well, I think this is a function of the parameter $\theta$

Comment: What are you viewing as random here?  The data, the parameter, or both?

Comment: Data. Parameters are usually assumed to be fixed.

Comment: In a Bayesian setting parameters are treated as random.  When the randomness occurs only through the data, I believe your question has no general answer: it must depend on the model as well as $\theta$ itself.  In many cases this covariance must be tiny, but in some circumstances--such as when $\theta$ lies near the boundary of the parameter space--it cannot vanish.